# Set unique active Components using $emit in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have issues with setting unique active Components using $emit in VueJS.

I want when to click to Tab A in tabbar components, It'll `be active in Tab A, not active in Tab B` and the same to Tab B.

Hope your guy helps.

**Parent Component:**

```
<template>
  <div class="tab-a" v-if="taba = true">
    <span>This is Tab A</span>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-b" v-if="tabb = true">
    <span>This is Tab B and I want Tab A is not Active</span>
  </div>
  <tabbar @open="ToggleOpen"></tabbar>
</template>
<script>
   ToggleOpen: function (obj) {
      obj.current = true
      obj.rest = false
    },
</script>
```

**Tab Bar Component:**

```
<template>
  <div class="photo_react">
    <li @click="open({current: 'taba', rest: 'tabb'})" class="tab-a" data-tooltip="Open TabA">Open TabA</li>
    <li @click="open({current: 'tabb', rest: 'taba'})" class="tab-b" data-tooltip="Open TabB">Open TabB</li>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    opencomment: function (obj) {
      this.$emit('open', obj)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: In `v-if`, it looks you just use variable assignment. That might needs to be a double equals. eg: `v-if="taba == true"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need to separate components into two? I came up with this simple implementation for tab switching.

```
<template>
  <div class="tab-a" v-if="currentTab == 'taba'">
    <span>This is Tab A</span>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-b" v-if="currentTab == 'tabb'">
    <span>This is Tab B and I want Tab A is not Active</span>
  </div>
  <div class="photo_react">
    <li @click="swtichTab('taba')" class="tab-a" data-tooltip="Open TabA">Open TabA</li>
    <li @click="switchTab('tabb')" class="tab-b" data-tooltip="Open TabB">Open TabB</li>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        currentTab: 'taba'
      }
    },

    methods: {
      switchTab(tab) {
        this.currentTab = tab;
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```